# How to create a WP account for an user already in CiviCRM?

Tags: user-account, caldera-forms

We have contacts in CiviCRM and we want them to create a WP account to access some specific front-end content. We're using a caldera form to let them register themselves.
But if I use a test contact I get `This email address is already in use.`

How could I proceed? Is this possible?
(CiviCRM 5.35.1 on WP 5.7)

Comment: could you not send them a checksum link to a Profile that has 'create user' required on it?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Caldera add on plugin to create wp user if yes than i guess its a question to ask Caldera support team.

Also can you check the email address you used already has wp user account or there is an entry in civicrm_uf_match table under uf_name column

Comment: actually I found :-) I just needed to create a process to register on WordPress but not in CiviCRM. The conflict was coming from the CiviCRM side where I was both creating a contact on CiviCRM and adding it to a group. I can still add to the group and it works like a charm.